# Are there some open source CAD libraries in Java?

Tags: java, cad

I need a CAD modeling library.
I've found such libraries, for example OPEN CASCADE, but they are not written in Java.To use those libraries I need a long time to learn a new programming language.

Now that I'm familiar with Java. Is there anyone who knows some open source CAD modeling libraries in Java?

Comment: Have you searched the Web for what you need? There seem to be many options... why are they not good enough?

Comment: I've searched the Web, and found that commonly used CAD libraries are hardly written in Java. So i ask which java library I can rely on.

Answer (score 5):

> Ycad is a library of CAD functions in Java. Currently only DXF is
>   supported for reading, viewing and writing. The DXF drawing may be
>   rendered to a Graphics object for printing or imaging.
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/ycad/

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 2):

May be this http://jcae.sourceforge.net/architecture.html could give you more info on how to achieve similar goals. If you have strong bias for java, it would try to use a "JNA" with OPEN CASCADE.